# Under what circumstances can a foreigner enter Singapore without presenting proof of onward travel?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, borders, singapore, proof-of-onward-travel

Among Singapore's entry requirements for visiting foreigners (accessed [here](http://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/consular_information/foreigners_visiting_singapore.html)) is:

> Onward or return ticket (if applicable)

When is this requirement not applicable?

Comment: I got into Singapore without proof of onward travel. I booked a one-way ticket since I was going on student exchange and waiting for the student residence permit and the person at the immigration desk accepted that after a couple questions without me having to provide any proof for that.

Comment: Thanks @drat. So I guess in absence of an onward ticket you just need to persuade the immigration officer you won't overstay.

Comment: Yes, that was my impression as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In my experience they do. Or at least the airline which will get you there will require you to have an exit ticket in order to board.

I was traveling from Phuket to Singapore without an exit ticket from Singapore (although I had an exit ticket from Sydney 2 weeks after) and the airline wouldn't let me board without an exit ticket.
It was a pain. In the end I ended buying a $40 ticket at the airport which I never used.

I know this answer lacks any specific information regarding actual regulations, I am just sharing my experience. Hope it helps.

EDIT: When I answered this question the title was "Does Singapore require all tourists to present proof of onward travel?"

Comment: This is helpful, since it means the exceptions are probably arcane enough they won't apply to me. I'll accept it for now, until/unless someone comes along explaining what the exceptions in fact are.